# Hatcher’s Proof of Borsuk-Ulam theorem for $S^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

[image]

[image]

I don't understand the implication in the boxed line or why $q$ is odd. In the mentioned proof of the fundamental group of $S^1$ the covering map was $p(s)=(\cos2 \pi s, \cos2 \pi s )$. i don't see how we can use the same covering map here. Any ideas what is the map $p$ here and how it gives the implication? thanks

(This is from Algebraic Topology by Hatcher, page 33)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $p(s) = e^{2\pi i s}$. Therefore $h(t) = p \tilde{h}(t) = e^{2\pi i \tilde{h}(t)}$ and 
$$e^{2\pi i\tilde{h}(s+1/2)} = h(s+1/2) = -h(s) = e^{\pi i}e^{2\pi i\tilde{h}(s)} = e^{2\pi i\tilde{h}(s) + \pi i} .$$
This equation implies that
$$2\pi i\tilde{h}(s+1/2) = 2\pi i\tilde{h}(s) + \pi i + 2k\pi i$$
for some $k \in \mathbb Z$. Hence
$$\tilde{h}(s+1/2) = \tilde{h}(s) + 1/2 + k = \tilde{h}(s) + q/2$$
with $q = 2k+1$.

**Edited on request:**

Hatcher shows that $h$ represents $q$-times the standard generator of $\pi_1(S^1)$. Since $q$ is odd, we have $q \ne 0$, thus $h$ represents a non-zero element of $\pi_1(S^1)$. We conclude that $h$ is not nullhomotopic.

Comment: thanks. may I ask a follow up question? why does $q$ odd imply non nullhomotopy of $h$?

Comment: It implies non-nullhomotopy of $h$. See my edit.

Comment: Sir  i have some confusion @PaulFrost $$e^{2\pi i\tilde{h}(s+1/2)}   = e^{2\pi i\tilde{h}(s) + \pi i} .$$
This equation implies that
$2\pi i\tilde{h}(s+1/2) = 2\pi i\tilde{h}(s) + \pi i .$

Im not getting  why do you add  $2k\pi i?$

Comment: @jasmine The exponential function is not injective. If you have $e^a = e^b$  then $a, b$ differ by a summand $2k\pi i$.

Comment: OK,that’s clear, thank you sir @PaulFrost  Can you recommend a good book for Algebraics topology for beginner ?

Comment: @jasmine It is difficult to give a recommendation. Of course I know many titles, but the only two books I have really used are "Spanier, Edwin H. Algebraic topology. Springer Science & Business Media, 1989" and "Switzer, Robert M. Algebraic topology-homotopy and homology. Springer, 2017". The first editions are very old, I bought them when I was a student, more then 45 years ago. Both books do not provide much motivation, but they are very concise. Switzer is perhaps a bit too "short" for beginners.